# Yii2: Match excel column with master record

Tags: php, excel, yii2, phpexcel, fieldset

I am working on `yii2`. I have a master table called `sims` in my DB and all the records are saved and updated in it. In my GUI these records are maintained in `SIM List`. Now, there is a use-case in which I am issuing the sims to a person. The issuance is done by two ways

1. Using create form
2. Via excel file

Both cases are running perfectly. Now, issuing sims via excel file, I want to check `imsi` number(s) whether they are available in the master record or not.

Bellow is my `Import` controller

```
 public function actionImport(){
    $file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
    $header_index = $_POST['header_index'];
    $fieldSet = $_POST['field'];


    $data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::widget([
        'mode' => 'import',
        'fileName' => 'uploads/' . $file_name,
        'setFirstRecordAsKeys' => false, // if you want to set the keys of record column with first record, if it not set, the header with use the alphabet column on excel.
        'setIndexSheetByName' => false, // set this if your excel data with multiple worksheet, the index of array will be set with the sheet name. If this not set, the index will use numeric.
        'getOnlySheet' => 0, // you can set this property if you want to get the specified sheet from the excel data with multiple worksheet.
    ]);

    //loop therogh first sheet
    $ok_count = 0;
    $status_arr = [];
    $final_data = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : $data;
    foreach($final_data as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key <= $header_index) continue;
        $sims = new SimIssueanceTransaction();

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){


            $v = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v));
            if(isset($fieldSet[0]['imsi']) && $fieldSet[0]['imsi']==$k){
                $sims->sim_id = Sims::imsiToidexcel($v);
                $sims->imsi =$v."";

            }

            if(isset($fieldSet[0]['issued_to']) && $fieldSet[0]['issued_to']==$k){
                $sims->issued_to = $v;
            }

            if (isset($fieldSet[0]['purpose']) && $fieldSet[0]['purpose'] == $k) {
                $sims->purpose = $v;
            }

        }
        $sims->issued_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sims->issued_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $sims->historic =1;

        if($sims->purpose=='Local SIM Issue')
        {
            $sims->status = Sims::$status_titles[1];
            Sims::change_status($sims->sim_id,Sims::$status_titles[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $sims->status = Sims::$status_titles[2];
            Sims::change_status($sims->sim_id,Sims::$status_titles[2]);
        }


        if($sims->save())
        {
            $ok_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $status_arr[] = $sims->errors;
        }


    }

    return $this->render('excel_finish', ['records_saved' => $ok_count,'status_arr'=>$status_arr]);
}
```

I want to add a check in bellow condition

```
if(isset($fieldSet[0]['imsi']) && $fieldSet[0]['imsi']==$k){
                $sims->sim_id = Sims::imsiToidexcel($v);
                $sims->imsi =$v."";

            }
```

**Update 1**

My `Sims` model is below

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['imsi','operator_name','data_details','sms_details','status'], 'required'],
        [['created_by', 'updated_by', 'sim_stauts', 'issued_to', 'returned_by', 'historic'], 'integer'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at','returned_at'], 'safe'],
        [['imsi', 'operator_name', 'data_details', 'sms_details','bill_date'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['sim_number', 'status','credit_limit','plan_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['monthly_bill'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        //[['imsi'], 'unique'],
        [['created_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['created_by' => 'id']],
    ];
}
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'imsi' => 'Imsi',
        'sim_number' => 'Sim Number',
        'operator_name' => 'Operator Name',
        'data_details' => 'Data Details',
        'sms_details' => 'Sms Details',
        'monthly_bill' => 'Monthly Bill',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        'sim_stauts' => 'Sim Stauts',
        'issued_to' => 'Issued To',
        'returned_by' => 'Returned By',
        'historic' => 'Version',
        'returned_at'=>'Returned At',
        'bill_date' => 'Billing Date',
        'credit_limit' => 'Credit Limit',
        'plan_name'=> 'Plan Name'
    ];
}
```

**Update 2**

As per suggestion I have created a function

```
 protected function findImsi($imsi){

    if(($model=Sims::findOne(['imsi'=>$imsi]))!== null){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }


}
```

Then in my `import` controller

```
foreach($final_data as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key <= $header_index) continue;
        $sims = new SimIssueanceTransaction();

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){

            $v = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v));
            $imsiValid = isset($fieldSet[0]['imsi']) && $fieldSet[0]['imsi'] == $k && $this->findImsi($v);

            if ($imsiValid) {
                $sims->sim_id = Sims::imsiToidexcel($v);
                $sims->imsi = $v . "";
            }
            else
            {

                \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', '
 <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
 <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
 <strong>Error!!! No Record is inserted..</strong> IMSI must be wrong </div>');
                return $this->redirect(['simissueancetransaction/excel']);
            }
.
.
.
}
.
.
.
}
```

While uploading an excel file with correct values in it, the `$imsiValid` is `true` but still it's not entering the `if` condition

By doing `var_dump($final_data);` I got the following result

```
array(3) { [1]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(4) "imsi" ["B"]=> string(9) "issued to" ["C"]=> string(7) "purpose" ["D"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(18) "899204031015192575" ["B"]=> float(134) ["C"]=> string(20) "Production SIM Issue" ["D"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(4) { ["A"]=> string(18) "899204031015192576" ["B"]=> float(134) ["C"]=> string(20) "Production SIM Issue"} }
```

**Update 3**

Below are the other two action controller functions for upload excel file.

```
  public function actionExcel(){

    $file_name = "excel_" . Yii::$app->user->id . ".xlsx";

    $error = "";
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = $path_parts['extension'];

        if(!in_array($extension,['xlsx','xls'])){

            $error = "Invalid file";
        }else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $file_name)) {

                $this->redirect(Url::to('process?file_name=' . $file_name . "&header_no=" . $_POST['header_no']));
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render("excel",['error'=>$error]);
}
public function actionProcess(){

    $file_name = $_GET['file_name'];

    // $data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::import("uploads/test.xlsx"); // $config is an optional

    try {
        $header_index = $_GET['header_no'];

        $data = \moonland\phpexcel\Excel::widget([
            'mode' => 'import',
            'fileName' => 'uploads/' . $file_name,
            'setFirstRecordAsKeys' => false, // if you want to set the keys of record column with first record, if it not set, the header with use the alphabet column on excel.
            'setIndexSheetByName' => false, // set this if your excel data with multiple worksheet, the index of array will be set with the sheet name. If this not set, the index will use numeric.
            'getOnlySheet' => 0, // you can set this property if you want to get the specified sheet from the excel data with multiple worksheet.
        ]);
        if (isset($data[0])) {
            $headers = $data[0][$header_index];
        } else {
            $headers = $data[$header_index];
        }

    }catch (Exception $x){
        die("Error");
    }

    return $this->render('excel_options',['headers'=>$headers,'file_name'=>$file_name,'header_index'=>$header_index]);

}
```

After these two function the `import` function is called

The model in which all the records are saved and updated is `Sims`.

How can I match the IMSI number with the master record?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `sims` have the `imsi` number saved in it and you want to check against that table first if it exists there or not?

Comment: added an answer see if it works

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes exactly I want to check the `imsi` and if any of the `imsi` is not available then it would not be inserted.

Comment: considering the sample data you provided what is the expected value of the `$header_index` and how does this `if($key <= $header_index)` condition evaluates, what would you post for the header_index

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam kindly check my `update 3`. You'll get a clearer picture

Comment: this is not what i was asking for i was asking that what do you  have in the `$header_index = $_POST['header_index'];`  inside your import action

Comment: The row value. it can be up to 8

Comment: this is strange i am unable to replicate it at my end the only condition the `imsiValid` is false is when the `fieldSet` indexes do not match you should verify the data coming from excel is in the correct order or not otherwise it is not the case it is simple as suggested in the answer below which is verify the sim number before insertion and return `true` or `false` in either case.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am also not sure what is the main issue. As without this check, I am able to upload the data.

Comment: try moving `if($this->findModel($v))` inside the `if ($imsiValid) {` and remove `$this->findModel($v)` from the prevoious line.

Comment: i have updated the answer see the replace section to understand what i am asking to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i have understood from your question is that you have `Sims` model in which you have saved all the sims along with the `imsi` and before you insert any record into the `SimIssueanceTransaction` you want to verify if it exists in the `Sims` or not.

If this is correct then take the following steps

Add a method to your controller

```
protected function findModel($imsi){
    if(($model=Sims::findOne(['imsi'=>$imsi])) !== null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then replace these lines

```
$v = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v));
if (isset($fieldSet[0]['imsi']) && $fieldSet[0]['imsi'] == $k) {
    $sims->sim_id = Sims::imsiToidexcel($v);
    $sims->imsi = $v . "";
}
```

with the following

```
$v = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v));
$imsiValid = isset($fieldSet[0]['imsi']) && $fieldSet[0]['imsi'] == $k;

if ($imsiValid) {
  if($this->findModel($v)){
    $sims->sim_id = Sims::imsiToidexcel($v);
    $sims->imsi = $v . "";
  }
}
```

> Note :I assume that `$v` will have the `imsi` when
>   `$fieldSet[0]['imsi']==$k` as you are setting `$sims->imsi = $v` inside the condition, other wise change `$this->findModel($v)`
>   accordingly

Comment: I have tried your answer. In either way, it's not entering inside the `if ($imsiValid)`. I have checked the value of `imsiValid` and it's `bool(true)` whether the imsi is correct or not

Comment: Also `$v` have imsi #

Comment: that is strange can you add the model code for `SIM` how can it return true if the `imsi` is incorrect the record wont be found and the `->one()` returns `null` which will skip to the last statement `return false`. @MrFaisal

Comment: i replaced the `find()->where()->one() ` with `findOne()` although it is just a short-hand but try once and confirm when the `imsi` is incorrect does it really returns true although it cant be, check if your column names are correct

Comment: Now it's giving me `false` whether the `imsi` is correct or not. The field name is same for both models

Comment: @MrOmer, I have added my `sim` model.

Comment: this is strange ...? can you `var_dump()` inside the findModel and see what it prints against the `imsi` number searched @MrFaisal

Comment: By doing ` var_dump($imsi);
        exit();` inside my `findImsi` function. The output I am getting is `string(18) "899204031015192577"` @MrOmer

Comment: and what does the model info show does it show any record

Comment: ` var_dump($model);` is giving me `NULL`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166671/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-mr-faisal). @MrFaisal

Comment: @MrOmer, My bad I was trying to upload excel file while I don't have anything in my master table so that's why I was getting `NULL` and `false`. But now I have inserted some data into my master table and then try to issue sims via excel file. Though it's returning me `true` but still it's not going inside `if ($imsiValid)`. Don't know why it's happening

Comment: By checking `var_dump($imsiValid);` before the condition it's giving `bool(true)` but when I check same in `else` condition it's giving me `bool(false)`. It's very strange.

Comment: how could this be is it has `true` it should go inside the if anyhow?

Comment: That's where i am also confused

Comment: you must be doing something wrong it doesnot work that way, look at all the values at the point when a imsi is available in the `fieldset` variable try `var_dump` with the `$fieldset` too to see what they are having otherwise if the value is Boolean true/false it should act accordingly if the value is `true` it will go inside `if` and if `false` thenit will go inside `else` and how come you are saying that it is not going inside the if have you tried to echo any string inside if

Comment: Yes I have tried `echo` inside `if` but it's not going inside

Comment: by `var_dump($fieldSet);` I got the following result `array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["imsi"]=> string(1) "A" ["issued_to"]=> string(1) "B" ["purpose"]=> string(1) "C" } }`

Comment: how many records are there in `finaldata` array that you are iterating  print_r and paste in question all resultset

Comment: why are you using 2 foreach loops for the finaldata array there isnt any array inside the name=>value paris in the `finaldata`

Comment: `$value` includes the data `array(3) { ["A"]=> string(18) "899204031015192575" ["B"]=> float(134) ["C"]=> string(20) "Production SIM Issue" }`

Comment: @MrOmer, I have tried your updated code, I want to add something. Actually, I want to check 2 things `1`. The `SIM` be issued whether it is in the `sims` table `2`. That SIM should be already issued.

Comment: For this, I have changed the `findImsi($imsi)` function a bit. 

`($model=Sims::find()->where(['imsi'=>$imsi])->andWhere(['status'=>'Inventory Stored SIM'])`

The status `Inventory Stored SIM` is the initial status of the SIM and If any of the SIM is not in `sims` and not have `Inventory Stored SIM` status, then it won't be issued

Comment: I tried to import `6` records out of them one IMSI # is not in the `sims` table. So whether the SIM status is `Inventory Stored SIM` or not the other `5` records are still issued again as I have already issued them.

Comment: There was an issue in the `if` condition so I updated it 
`if(($model=Sims::find()->where(['imsi'=>$imsi])->andWhere(['status'=>'Inventory Stored SIM'])
                ->orWhere(['status'=>'SIM Returned'])->one())!== null)` and now all the things are working. Thank you for your help :)